# Medicare tax 2013 formula

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to create an Excel formula that will take a number entered into a specific cell (I'll use B6 for ease of reference), and do the following:

> If B6 is less than or equal to $200,000, then B6 * 1.45%   AND 
>   If B6 is greater than $200,000, then (($200,000*1.45%)+(every dollar above
>   $200,000 * 2.35%))

For example, if B6 = $225,000 then the first $200,000 would be multiplied by 1.45% and the remaining $25,000 would be multiplied by 2.35%.  (With both calculations added together)

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(B6<=200000, B6*0.0145, (200000*0.0145) + ((B6-200000)*0.0235))
```

The structure of the `IF` formula is basically `IF(condition, trueResult, falseResult)`

You could also replace the `(200000*0.0145)` with a constant of `2900`, but I included the full calculation for illustration.

Comment: That worked great until B6 > $200,000.  With this formula, when B6=$225,000, then the formula lends the value $223,200.00.  But the actual answer should be $3,487.50.  Can you help me fine the error?

Comment: You might have a typo - I just copy-pasted it into a blank Excel sheet to test it and correctly got 3487.5

Comment: I'm not sure what I did wrong but, you are right, it's working now.  Thanks so much!!!